# NextJS Changes Not Showing in Docker Conatiner

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, next.js

I am having problems viewing my changes to my NextJS app in my Docker container. I am not sure if this is a caching issue on the NextJS side or Docker side. I am new to Docker and NextJS, so I may be missing something basic here.

Frontend Dockerfile

```
# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM node:16-alpine AS deps

WORKDIR /frontend

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json package-lock.json*  ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .


RUN npm run build

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

NodeJS Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /server

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --omit=dev

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

Docker Compose

```
version: '1.0'

services: 
    api: 
      build: ./server
      container_name: api
      restart: always
      ports: 
        - 8000:8000
      networks:
        - backend
        - frontend
    frontend:
      env_file: ./.env
      container_name: frontend
      depends_on:
        - api
      build:
        context: ./frontend
      ports:
        - 3000:3000
      networks:
        - frontend  


networks:
  backend:
  frontend:
```

I have tried deleting containers and images and rebuilding with `docker compose up -d`  . My changes didn't show. I also tried doing the same thing but running `docker system prune` . Still nothing. I am guessing this has something to do with the NextJS build cache/files. I have ran an npm run build which has files from a previous test build, would I need to delete certain files/folders from the .next folder? I tried finding similar issues and documentation on this but had no luck. Any help/links would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the second `COPY . .` in the frontend Dockerfile after the build. That might be copying an old build you ran locally into the container overwriting the new build.

You should also add a `.dockerignore` file to prevent copying your `node_modules` and development environment like `.env.local` files into the image.

I'd recommend reading through the docs here to learn more about what `next build` does, and their recommended way to use Docker. https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment

This thread also does a good job of explaining Dockerfiles for node  https://twitter.com/sidpalas/status/1634194026500096000